# how to add days to a date column from an Integer column, by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, int

I have Column 'A' which is a date column `CREATED AS CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` and column 'B' which is an integer column.

I want to create column C to show A+B as a date.

Comment: [DATEADD is your friend. Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: I tried, but in my column B (integer) are different values, and I don't want to add days as 1,2 or 4. I want to add days from Column B To column A to show the result in Column C

Comment: There's no need of writing any numbers. They are taken from your Int-Column. I just added an answer...

Comment: Tag the dbms product used. (GETDATE is a product specific function.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres and Oracle you can simply do `a + b`

Comment: SQL server...Sorry, I'm new on this site and also in SQL :) I will pay more attention on tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
CREATE TABLE #test(DateColumn DATETIME, IntColumn INT);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
 ({ts'2016-01-01 00:00:00'},1)
,({ts'2016-01-10 11:30:00'},-2)
,(GETDATE(),3);

SELECT DateColumn AS A
      ,IntColumn AS B
      ,DATEADD(DAY,IntColumn,DateColumn) AS C
FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Btw: Adding full DAYs would even work with simple `DateValue+IntValue`